# Date problem after restore

Tags: backups

I had to restore a drupal 7 site from scheduled backup using backup & migrate. Since then I seem to have problem with date/timestamp.
I have a view (3.6) filtering on node created date with options between "today" and "tomorrow".
All users are in GMT+7 timezone.
It is now 18:01pm here and the sql query generated has:
node.created BETWEEN 1375959700-25200 AND 1375959700+61200

So "today" is current time instead of today at 00:00:00

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 7 They are not using the datetime field. instead of that you can use the int field and add your date in unixtime stamp format.

You can expose the data using hook_views_data hook. Check following URL for more help:

https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_data/7